# Can't navigate to children using router

Tags: angular, routes

I have an Angular 2 app and navigation works fine as follow:

```
{ path: 'layer1/layer2', component: C2 } }
{ path: 'layer1/layer2/layer3', component: C3, canDeactivate: [CanDeactivateGuard] }  },
```

And in C2 I have a link which references C3 as follows:

```
[routerLink]="['./layer3']
```

I then tried to make layer3 a child of layer2, so my routes look like this:

```
{ path: 'layer1/layer2', component: C2 },  children: [
    { path: 'layer3', component: C3, canDeactivate: [CanDeactivateGuard] } 
] }
```

However whenever I do so I can no longer navigate to layer3 (C3).  The layer2 component (C2) remains on screen.

I've read the Angular 2 docs on children routing here [Routing With Children](https://angular.io/guide/router) but I can't figure out what's wrong with this link route table.

Comment: Did you go through the section on relative navigation: https://angular.io/guide/router#relative-navigation? That covers how to navigate paths in the hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

You need a path empty for do children try this:

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'layer1/layer2', pathMatch: 'full' },   
    { path: 'layer1/layer2', component: C2 },  children: [
        { path: 'layer3', component: C3, canDeactivate: [CanDeactivateGuard], outlet: "layer" } 
    ] }
```

In you controller do this function

```
public goToComponent(url) {
        this._router.navigate(["layer/layer1/layer2", { outlets: { "layer": url } }]);
    }
```

Use

```
goToComponent('layer3')
```

HTML

```
<router-outlet name="layer"> </router-outlet>
```

Comment: I actually have an empty path route at the topmost level:   { path: '', redirectTo: 'welcome', pathMatch: 'full' } so that's not it

Comment: Try adding outlets, you empty level should redirect to route that contains children and in your code is layer1/layer2 who contains children